# 'Hold him' and 'hold his hand'

Tags: ambiguity

If I hold someone's hand, I can express it as 'I hold him.' Then, how can I exactly describe I only hold someone's hand, not the other parts of his body? Is just saying 'I hold his hand' enough?

Comment: "I hold him" does not convey the idea of holding someone's hand.  You have to say, "I hold his hand" or "I hold him by the hand."

Comment: "Holding someone" usually implies embracing them in your arms.

Comment: Yes, saying that you hold *body part* is enough, because you're describing exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. "Hold his hand" and "Hold him" have different meanings in natural illogical real English.

"Hold him" implies "hug" or "embrace him".

> Tears were forming in his eyes, so I held him until he stopped crying.

But saying "I held his *body part*" is enough

> I held his hand and we walked together along the beach.

> I held his waist and threw him into the air.

Answer (score 0):

> If I hold someone's hand, I can express it as 'I hold him.'

**No. That is not true in English.**

[image]

[image]